# How can I write this query with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Let's say I have a method like this:

```
public function scopeWithLikes(Builder $query)
    {
        $query->leftJoinSub(
            'select likeable_id, sum(liked) likes, sum(!liked) dislikes from likes group by likeable_id',
        );
    }
```

My question is, how can I rewrite this query with Eloquent for my Laravel project?

Comment: You can make a relation function in eloquent and use `withCount()` to get the count of likes and dislikes.

Comment: @AnkitSingh So you mean something like this: `$likes = Like::select(['likeable_id'])->withCount(['liked','!liked'])->get();` ?

Comment: @AnkitSingh Then how can I add `group by`

Comment: Read Here: https://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-withcount-get-related-records-amount. You can pass the closure function. And then you can add any additional condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood I think this is what you are looking for, try it and tell me:

```php
$orders = DB::table('likes')
                ->select('likeable_id', DB::raw('SUM(liked) as likes'), DB::raw('SUM(!liked) as dislikes'))
                ->groupBy('likeable_id')
                ->get();
```

You can get more information from the laravel Database documentation **Query Builder** here:

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-methods